# mocha and mongoose timeout

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm using mocha and mongoose and my beforeEach() and afterEach() function keeps hanging. It gives me an error:

```
object model "before each" hook:
Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded
```

The callback never seems to be called.  What can I do to initialize the database for my tests?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
describe('Object model', function(){
    before(function(callback){
        if(mongoose.connection.db)
            return callback();
        else
            mongoose.createConnection(testDB.url, callback);
    });

    after(function(callback){
        mongoose.connection.close(callback)
    });

    beforeEach(function(callback){
        VerifyText.create({number:'12223334444', code: '1342'},function(err){
            callback(err);
        });
    })
    afterEach(function(callback){
        VerifyText.remove({},callback)
    })
    it('should not crash', function(callback){
        should.exist(true)
        callback();
    }) 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue probably comes from using mongoose.createConnection instead of mongoose.connect. Mongoose populates mongoose.connection which you use above only when using .connect, in case of .createConnection it returns connection object from createConnection function.

(Little late answer but I found your question during search for my own issue with createConnection)